# Is there anything like an Excel IF Statement in SQL

Tags: sql

Just wanted to see if there is a way to output a result that is not stored based on the addition of up to 4 fields?

Have a table that holds the count of passengers on a service for different categories, Adult, Child Infant and staff, and I want to try and out put a number based on the result of these fields that is not stored.

For example if the result of the add is >15 then output 45, if > 9 output 35.  the output is the size of the coach that is required.

I know I can do it in Excel after the data is extracted but was wondering if it can be done before and included with the data?

Any suggestions and help appreciated.

Comment: SQL for which server? Most SQL dialects have an `IF()` function.  Check your documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a query on the data:

```
select t.*,
       (case when Adult + Child + Infant + staff > 15 then 45
             when Adult + Child + Infant + staff > 9 then 35
        end) as CoachSize
from t;
```

You can also do this using a `view` so it is available as if it were a table:

```
create view vw_t as
    select t.*,
           (case when Adult + Child + Infant + staff > 15 then 45
                 when Adult + Child + Infant + staff > 9 then 35
            end) as CoachSize
    from t;
```

And, in some databases, you can add a computed column directly into the table definition.

Comment: Thank you all excellent suggestions and lots for me to have a look at for future things but for this have used the one from Gordon as it can fit in with the rest of the query I have.  Again thank you for all your help, appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what SQL program you're using, most offer the `CASE WHEN` statement (see this [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e416c/1))

```
CREATE TABLE CaseValues(
  Value INT
)

INSERT INTO CaseValues
VALUES (1)
  , (16)
  , (9)

SELECT CASE WHEN Value > 15 THEN 45
  WHEN Value BETWEEN 6 AND 14 THEN 35
  ELSE 25 END AS Result
FROM CaseValues
```

You can also use `CASE WHEN` on multiple columns, [see this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b7669/1).

Comment: The `CASE` expression is part of the SQL Standard and is in most SQL implementations, including all of the major ones.

Answer (score 2):

The Standard SQL `CASE` expression is the closest equivalent to the Excel `IF(..)` function:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN Col1=Col2 THEN 'Foo'
         WHEN Col1>Col2 THEN 'Bar'
         WHEN Col3 Is NULL THEN Col4
         ELSE 'unknown'
    END  As [CaseColumn]
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CASE statement. Here is the syntax.

```
    SELECT 
    CASE WHEN DayOfBirth > 15 
            THEN 45
         WHEN DayOfBirth > 9
            THEN 35
        ELSE
             0
    END
    FROM BirthDaysTable
```